# Is it enough to upgrade Java JDK/JRE if still compiling with an old java.version?

Tags: java, druid

I'm using an open-source project which still uses Java 8. It supports Java 11, but the pom.xml locks the compiled byte-code version to 8:

```
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
```

I would like to avoid using Java 8, for security risk reasons.
Is it enough to compile and execute with Java 11, even though the byte-code is set to Java 8.

Comment: It is the first step to get the application up and running quickly, you still need to complete the transition